# TypeScript class implements interface

Tags: typescript

Why can the following code be complied correctly, rather than the compiler raising an error `Type '() => number' is not assignable to type '() => void'.`?

```
 interface ClockInterface {
      currentTime: Date;
      f() : void;
    }
    
    class Clock implements ClockInterface {
      sdd : unknown = undefined
      currentTime: Date = new Date();
       f():number{
             return 8
       }
      constructor(h: number, m: number){}
    }
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQSwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZWAYQDYHskGsCSksiKwA3gLABQwwSArjDFJACogC2UAXMACIJoAbmq04ACgCUwXgDcsIACYiqAX2rUkGBAGcd6bHlAcADhihdI+zDgJF4yVJRrAdixTOD0wuMFgDuYMAAvF5gilBw4FCKonSMzGycPPyCqKFgUP6p0FIqtGJS3GD0HABGsM4FBcwQjEEAHHG06i5IWGA6EDD0SBBYMOIAFrwl5bAANMAco6UVMJJkrapAA)

Comment: Because `() => number` *is* assignable to `() => void`. If all the consumers access the function through an interface that says "nothing gets returned", hence never assign or use the return value, it doesn't matter if there actually is one.

Comment: @VLAZ that's what the OP is saying, it unexpectedly *doesn't* error.

Comment: f() : void are different from  f():number, its not understanding

Comment: @jonrsharpe ah, I've completely misread the question, then. It mystified me because such an error couldn't normally occur. Here is the FAQ: [Why are functions returning non-`void` assignable to function returning `void`?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)

Comment: @qqqer they're *different*, but that doesn't mean they're not *compatible*. The other way around would be a problem, if all the consumers expect a number but you don't return anything (or rather, return undefined - JS doesn't really have void functions) things will break, but if your consumers expect nothing it doesn't really matter if something gets returned.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  thinks so much